# CakePHP and JQuery function .load()

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am trying to use the JQuery function .load() with cakePHP.

In my JS I have:

```
$("div.banery_top_lewy").load("www.example.eu/events/drawLargeBanner");
```

I have also added a RequestHandler component, then in the action drawLargeBanner I have echoed a link with an image. I was expecting that this would load the image into the mentioned div but its loads into the whole page instead.

---

//edit

Some of you suggested that if the JS is not from the same domain it may not work. Mine was from the same domain although it was not working. My solution to this problem was to change:

```
$("div.banery_top_lewy").load("www.example.eu/events/drawLargeBanner");
```

to

```
$("div.banery_top_lewy").load(".//events/drawLargeBanner");
```

Comment: Is `www.example.eu` the website where your javascript is from? If not, the call gets prevented by the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 2):

When you mean loads the whole page, do you mean it loads *everything* such as

```
<html
<!-- css bla bla -->
<body>
  <!-- content --> 
</body>
</html>
```

If so, try using the `ajax.ctp` layout that comes with Cake - it outputs *just* the content.

```
function drawLargeBanner() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

// you may need to create this layout, but it's usually found in a default cake install

```
//ajax.ctp
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

Create your view as normal.

It's essentially a blank layout, for use with ajax, presumably allowing you want you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes it loads whole page as you said. I have tried your suggestions but with no luck... Really dont`t know what can it be...

Comment: Check that layout exists and is definitely being used. what happens if you access `www.example.eu/events/drawLargeBanner` directly? what's the output

Comment: the layout is working because if i add some content to it it is rendered with this action www.example.eu/events/drawLargeBanner and this action gives what I want when accessed directly

Comment: Something else is wrong then; the `ajax` layout is specifically for working with AJAX, so only content gets returned, and no layout etc. If accessing it directly produces NO other output other than the "banner", then the problem lies elsewhere ~

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in to your action within your controller:

```
$this->autoLayout = false;
```

Comment: Moreover when I am trying to get to the action standard way it`s working - it renders what the action should render and without layout

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the action add this

```
$this->layout = null;
```

HTH